# $this->config->get('something') in opencart

Tags: php, oop, web, opencart, opencart2.x

I am newbie in opencart as well as in php. I am discovering opencart templates, I found  `$this->config->get` this line, I am a little bit confused about this. I don't understand clearly. This request we are using this object (current) access config object and call get method of config object, am I right ?
I have read that get query data from database. This data is set from admin panel.
So here are questions :
**1.** Where can I find config object declaration
**2.** Get uses simple query to retrieve data from database ? 
**3.** How can I add my own fields, I mean how can I add some fields in admin panel, for instance in category configuration to use them in this way  `$this->config->get`.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `<OC_ROOT>/system/library/config.php`
2. What do you mean by simple query? if `SELECT <COLUMN[S]> FROM <TABLE> WHERE <CONDITION[S]>` is simple for you, then **yes**
3. Too broad for answering here. Check the code for how the administration settings are handled, or settings from certain extensions/modules and You'll see. Basically if you insert some new rows into the `setting` table and provide a unique key for that setting you can retrieve it by calling `$this->config->get('<KEY>');`.

Comment: I admire your neat and elegant answers !